# pass hostname as a variable in ssh command

Tags: shell

I have this command in my shell script exampl1.sh:

```
host1=vizzia1
ssh user1@$host1  -o ServerAliveInterval=300 "ls /u01/app1/$host1/SCRIPTS/"
```

If I run shell script example1.sh, its saying  SCRIPTS not found, even though directory is there and with 755 permission.

```
$sh exampl1.sh
==============================================================================
..................
.................AUTHORIZED USE ONLY
...........
==============================================================================

ls: cannot access /SCRIPTS: No such file or directory
/u01/app1/vizzia1:
LOGS
SAVE
SCRIPTS
SCRIPTS_0921
templates
```

anyone help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's complaining about `/SCRIPTS/`, not `/u01/app1//SCRIPTS` as the code shown would if were simply an issue of `host1` not being set.

Comment: `sh -x exampl1.sh` would be a good place to start so you can get a lot of what's actually being executed. Maybe also add `set -x;` to the start of the remote command you're running over ssh.

Comment: your existing code _should_ work, as long as your hostname is sane and nonmalicious (if it were possible to write bash-only code instead of targeting sh, I'd be using either `printf %q` or `${var@Q}` to generate escaped versions of your variables). xtrace logs should make the failure mode clearer.

Comment: ...the error message is what I'd expect if your `host1` variable had a space in it, for example. `host1='vizzia1 '` would cause this bug.

Comment: Thankyou, I was able to find the issue after running by -X, I am assigning host to variable via script, instead of hard coded, so script automatically assigning space, so its not able to find the path, now I corrected it.